# Check cron job minimum span

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cron-task

I have an app that accepts a cron definition from the user

Now - let's say I want to limit how many crons the user can run -
so that the *minimum* span between each cron would be once an hour.

How can I check whether the provided cron-job "at most" or "most frequently" happens every hour.

I thought about validating that the first value is a number, but I feel like that's the wrong approach here